# HTML, CSS center H1 and P under Image

Tags: html, css, image, center

I'm in need of help to centre text under a few images. For some reason the text is off by a few. The `h3` needs to be on-top of the `p` and the `h3` & `p` needs to be center under the `img`

```css
/*--Experience--*/

.experience::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.exp-image {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 35px;
}

.exp-image h3 {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.exp-image p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!--Experience Section-->
<div class="experience">
  <div class="exp-image">
    <img src="images/Ps_Color.png" alt="">
    <h3>7</h3>
    <p>Years</p>
  </div>

  <div class="exp-image">
    <img src="images/Pr_Color.png" alt="">
    <h3>7</h3>
    <p>Years</p>
  </div>

  <div class="exp-image">
    <img src="images/Ae_Color.png" alt="">
    <h3>7</h3>
    <p>Years</p>
  </div>

  <div class="exp-image">
    <img src="images/Ai_Color.png" alt="">
    <h3>7</h3>
    <p>Years</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Don't float the `h3` or `image` it's not necessary. Just apply `text-align:center` to `..exp-image`.

Comment: @Paulie_D Without floating the images they are aligned underneath each other and not next to each other.

Comment: `float` the image wrappers...not their contents.

Comment: @Paulie_D okay its done, the h3 and p is now centered with each other but not with the image.

Answer (score 0):

give h3 and p width:100%, and text-align:center. The width 100% sets the width to the size of the parent container(the div).

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to remove  `float: left` from `.exp-image h3` in css

```css
/*--Experience--*/
.experience::after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.experience{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.exp-image {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.exp-image h3{
  display: block;
  width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.exp-image p{

    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!--Experience Section-->
<div class="experience">
    <div class="exp-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
        <h3>7</h3>
        <p>Years</p>
    </div>

    <div class="exp-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
        <h3>7</h3>
        <p>Years</p>
    </div>

    <div class="exp-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
        <h3>7</h3>
        <p>Years</p>
    </div>

    <div class="exp-image">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
        <h3>7</h3>
        <p>Years</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i think  class .exp-image have a fixed width and height 50px , but your actual pic size more than 50px. Try rewrite 
`.exp-image {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: actual pic size here ;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 35px;
}`

or you need to use column like bootstrap column for 4 - column grid like this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_four_columns.asp)

and try snippet above, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You could:

Remove `float:left;` from the `h3`.

And, add this CSS to the image so that it also centres:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Gives this:

[image]